# Vimscript: how do you map backspace or delete keys?

Tags: vim

Does anyone know how to map the backspace and delete keys in Vimscript?

Comment: If you do `:ctrl-k` and then press a key, vim will tell you how it's known to vim; i.e. `<BS>` and `<Del>`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Frederik : You should turn your comment into an answer. In insert mode, you can also use `ctrl-v` to insert the key alias (in a vim script for example)

Comment: Refer to `:help key-mapping`, particularly `:help map-special-keys` for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 27):

From Normal mode, you can type `:` then Press Ctrl+k followed by any key, and vim will tell you how to reference it.  For example, from normal mode typing `:` then pressing Ctrl+k and pressing Backspace results in:

`:<BS>`

Then you can remap like normal:

```
:map <BS> :echo 'You pressed backspace!'<CR>
:map <Del> :echo 'You pressed Delete!'<CR>
```

Obviously you'll want to do something more useful than that, so change the part from `:echo` onward.  [Here is a helpful tutorial to get started](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)) if you are new to remapping keys in vim.

Answer (score 5):

```
imap <Bs> BACK
imap <Del> DELETE
```